Adding multiple users to SharePoint Group using rest api with Power automate - It sometimes doesn't add all the users
I'm using power automate to add users to a patcicular SharePoint group.
Somtimes it adds the user sometimes it doesn't. Is this api reliable or can it only add one user at a time?
The api i'm using is (Leveraging Send an HTTP request to SharePoint)
_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('SharePoint Group')/users

Method : Post
Body :{ 
"__metadata": { "type": "SP.User" }, 
"LoginName": "i:0#.f|membership|Usersemailaddress" 
}

Are there any api to do this?
Thanks in advance

LoginName is not necessary user's e-mail, it's the User Principal Name (UPN). A user could not have an e-mail (technical account, security group), or the user's e-mail domain is not the same domain of the Entra ID domain in case of acquisition/merge between companies.
For example, John Doe could have an e-mail john.doe@lecacy-corp.com where its UPN is john.doe@newcorp.onmicrosoft.com, etc.
  { 
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.User" }, 
    "LoginName": "i:0#.f|membership|UserPrincipalName" 
  }


You can check the value of LoginName and Email on a particular site with this URL in your browser:
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/web/SiteUsers


References:

Is a UPN the same as an email address?
What is UPN (User Principal Name)?
Microsoft Entra UserPrincipalName population


Thanks jleture for your response.
In my case/environment the output from the rest api using using this
LogineName :i:0#.f|membership| joe.bloke@google.com
Email: joe.bloke@google.com
I can't see it using onmicrosoft.com
As I said sometimes the users are in sometimes not.
FYI - in my power automate the rest call is in side an Apply each and adds the users in the loop

So the same user can be added sometime, or can be in error? User must connect a first time on the site the be referenced.

The fix was strange  but I changed my query to start using ID instead of GetByName and its started working etter

Maybe because native groups are translated and depending the user of the connection the label is not the same. Using hardcoded ID is however a bad practice.

I know thabks. But at this stage its my only option
